# How to run command from bundle in app controller in Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, command-line

### INTRODUCTION

In my personal project I am using:

1. Symfony v3.2.7
2. PHP v7.1.1
3. [CravlerMaxMindGeoIpBundle](https://github.com/cravler/CravlerMaxMindGeoIpBundle)
4. [How to Call a Command from a Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html)
5. On Windows 10 Pro dev machine

### TARGET

I would like to run `CravlerMaxMindGeoIpBundle's` command `php bin/console cravler:maxmind:geoip-update` from controller successfully.

### PROBLEM

At the moment I have set up `CravlerMaxMindGeoIpBundle` bundle and command `php bin/console cravler:maxmind:geoip-update` works fine in command line.

Then I followed official documentation (4th link in intro section). Changed callable command of course. And yet I get an error.

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "cravler:maxmind" namespace.
```

### QUESTION

What should I do to run the command without an error?

### CODE

My action in controller

```
public function geoIpUpdateAction(Request $request)
{
    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput(array(
        'command' => 'cravler:maxmind:geoip-update'
    ));
    // You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
    $content = $output->fetch();

    // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
    dump($content);

    return $this->render('admin/geo_ip.html.twig');
}
```

My AppKernel with enabled bundles

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Bmatzner\FoundationBundle\BmatznerFoundationBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\TimeBundle\KnpTimeBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Cravler\MaxMindGeoIpBundle\CravlerMaxMindGeoIpBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

### FINALLY

What am I missing?

Comment: why dont you use the Process Component? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: @Veas Because I want to run command that exists in external bundle from my controller. As I understand it, `process` component is meant for ones own commands...

Comment: @Rikijs really no matter, the Process Component can do it too. However you code is right, so my question is: What is the environment where you are added this bundle in you AppKernel and what is the environment of this request?

Comment: This looks like this command doesn't exists because the bundle is not loaded or there is a typo.

Comment: @Veas I updated question with `AppKernel` file. I tried with app_dev.php and with app.php on dev machine. `Dev environment` returned error that is mentioned in the question, but `prod` environment showed my custom error page. I will add error logs for both environments in a moment.

Comment: As yceruto already answered my question correctly and logs do not yield any new information I decided no to include them in my question.

Comment: @Rikijs You can run any defined command with the process component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a common mistake to import:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
```

instead of:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
```

So make sure to import the second class (from FrameworkBundle) to load all configured commands (external or not) correctly.

Comment: Good catch - it was exactly the problem. With correct import command works! Thank You!