# There are no commands defined with command into controller symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to launch command into a controller symfony. I wrote method and it run correctly command mechanism because I have a return message.

But All command available in my symfony prompt shell command (php bin/console) is not recognize in my launcher command controller method.

I have all the time the same error message into outputBuffered object :
"There are no commands defined in the "XXXX" namespace"

Just one command seems to be run correctly : "help" 
But "list" command doesn't run.

My controller method which launch command component :

```
public function executeDoctrineSchemaAction()
{
    \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('here 1');

    $kernel      = $this->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel);

    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input  = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'debug:router']);
    $output = new BufferedOutput();

    $retval = $application->run($input, $output);

    $content = $output->fetch();
    \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump($content);
    return true;
}
```

Can you help me to understand why command run perfectly into my prompt application admin but not in my controller ?

EDIT : I use this class in my file : 
**use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;**
There is no similar with this kind of solution
The error is catched because it seems that not found namespace

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617903/how-to-run-command-from-bundle-in-app-controller-in-symfony3/43618819#43618819 to see if you've been affected with the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run command from bundle in app controller in Symfony3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617903/how-to-run-command-from-bundle-in-app-controller-in-symfony3)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunaly this is not a issue of use class in file dealing with Application class.

Comment: No duplicate issue

Comment: Using `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application` does not solve your issue? then check the environment where the command is available.