# How to call command form the controller in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a Command in Symfony that clears cache and removes all the translations from web directory. The command name is:

```
$this->setName('dump-translations')
```

And command is running from the console perfect, but when I call it from the controller I get the response:

```
Command "dump-translations" is not defined.
```

I quess I am missing some step but could not find the answer.
Here is the code:

```
namespace Pi\Bundle\WhiteLabelBundle\Controller;

use Pi\Bundle\WhiteLabelBundle\Command\DumpTranslationsCommand;
use Pi\Bundle\WhiteLabelBundle\YmlReader\YmlReader;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        (new YmlReader())->readYmlFile();

        echo $this->sendSpool();

        return $this->render('Pi\WhiteLabelBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function sendSpool()
    {
        $application = new Application($this->get('kernel'));

        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'dump-translations'
        ));

        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        $content = $output->fetch();

        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run command from bundle in app controller in Symfony3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617903/how-to-run-command-from-bundle-in-app-controller-in-symfony3)

Answer (score 4):

Possible solutions to improve your architecture (so you don't need to call command). You should extract functionality to a service and then you can use your service in controller and in command without need to run command from controller. Your codebase will be clearer.

Next possible thing - Run command via [Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)

Comment: IMO The cleanest solution is the first one (service)